# DBMS Scheduler logic required

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to set up a due date concept using DBMS scheduler below is the requirement .please suggest how I can achieve this using DBMS scheduler.
I am planning to pick this date from `dbms_scheduler` tables where it should calculate the date and hold in some column for referencing.

Requirement

- The due date needs to change every 6 months:
- For June: Last working Friday
- For Dec: Second-week ending date on Friday

e.g. For 2016 it should be 24 June 2016 & 9 Dec 2016

Comment: I know there is scheduling option in oracle but not sure how to implement with proper way.It would be great if u can share some pointers for knowing more on this

Comment: It would be great if anybody let me know details on this requirement please